# Study not working: Close and Open within 30% of Low, High more than 30% above Low

Tags: pine-script

i just have startet with pine script and i am struggleing with my simple script. May i ask you to help me out?

I want to mark all candels where the body is not bigger than 30% from the low.

This is what i try:

```
//@version=4
study("Close and Open within 30% of Low, High more than 30% above Low", overlay=true)

openWithin30Percent = open <= low * 1.3
closeWithin30Percent = close <= low * 1.3
highMoreThan30PercentAboveLow = high <= low * 1.6

condition = closeWithin30Percent and openWithin30Percent and highMoreThan30PercentAboveLow

// Plot
plotshape(series=condition ? close : na, color=color.green, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small)
```

But it displays all all candles...

Thank you very much!
c.